# Setting node name dynamically at boot time

Tags: erlang, relx

I am building my release using relx and I can not use the default `-sname someuser@127.0.0.1`.
Instead I would like to do something like -sname someuser@`hostname -i` to define the node's public IP at boot time. Using `-sname someuser@`hostname -i`` does not work because `hostname -i` is not expanded to a real IP. I tried to use net_kernel:start(xxxxxxx) but it did not work.

Is there any way to get a dynamic `-sname` in vm.args using relx ?

Thanks :)

Comment: With the sname parameter you can exclude the IP address entirely (e.g.,`-sname someuser`). Erlang will fill it in by default with the machines hostname (someuser@somemachine). Alternatively, you can use the full name parameter (`-name someuser`) and it will fill in the RDNS details for you as well (someuser@somemachine.somenetwork.com). Basically, I'd suggest not to worry about getting the IP address into vm.args and use DNS instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written [in the documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html) (and answered in the comments by **@Soup d'Campbells**), the `-sname` and `-name` flags do not need the hostname, and will automatically fill the `Host` part of the node's ID with the host'sid (short not fully qualified for -sname, FQDN for -name):

> **-sname** Name Makes the Erlang runtime system into a distributed node, similar to -name, but the host name portion of the node name Name@Host
>   will be the short name, not fully qualified.
>
> This is sometimes the only way to run distributed Erlang if the DNS
>   (Domain Name System) is not running. There can be no communication
>   between nodes running with the -sname flag and those running with the
>   -name flag, as node names must be unique in distributed Erlang systems.
>
> **-name** Name Makes the Erlang runtime system into a distributed node. This flag invokes all network servers necessary for a node to become
>   distributed. See net_kernel(3). It is also ensured that epmd runs on
>   the current host before Erlang is started. See epmd(1).
>
> The name of the node will be Name@Host, where Host is the fully
>   qualified host name of the current host. For short names, use the
>   -sname flag instead.

If you plan to use a distributed node, and you do have DNS in your domain, use the `-name` flag, as it will also invoke all necessary network servers (just as written above).

See for yourself:

```
$> erl -sname bouly
(bouly@myserver)1>

$> erl -name bouly
(bouly@myserver.myhome.net)1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have misfed `net_kernel:start()` with parameters. The proper form of argument is [Name, shortnames] or [Name, longnames]; Name is atom which shall be formed as "localpart" or "localpart@host" (likely you'll need `list_to_atom()` for this).
For example:

```
2> net_kernel:start(['abc@localhost', shortnames]).
{ok,<0.39.0>}
```

and, as result:

```
$ epmd -names
epmd: up and running on port 4369 with data:
name abc at port 46623
```