# Erlang - Remote communication, response

Tags: erlang

Failed to see this mentioned anywhere in the documentation but if a node remote communicate with another node can the receiving node respond to the sending node simply by using the PID contained in the "From" variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, see [the documentation for `erlang:send/2,3`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#send-2), which says:

> Dest may be a **remote** or local pid, a (local) port, a locally registered name, or a tuple {RegName, Node} for a registered name at another node.

Here, `Dest` refers to the destination of the message, and I highlighted the word "remote" in bold to show that a destination PID can refer to a remote process.

Comment: Great, makes thing easier. Thought I had to send the machine as an extra param.

Comment: Sorry for asking in the same thread but how does a node fetch its own machine name?

Comment: That would be hard to fully answer in a comment. See [net_kernel](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/net_kernel.html) and [net_adm](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/net_adm.html) for some details, and [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24928855/409228) is helpful too.